tar exits on "Cannot stat: No such file of directory", Please assist
I am trying to touch a file and then tar the file with following comamnd but it failing .. Please assist..
touch sample_touch_FILENAME.CSV
echo "sample_touch_FILENAME.CSV">FILELIST_PROJECT.txt

while read i
do
tar -cf "$i".tar "$i"
done<$DirPath/FILELIST_PROJECT.txt

Error Message:
tar: sample_touch_FILENAME.CSV: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Please assist.

What is the content of variable DirPath?

I am quite sure that the commands shown in the question are not exactly what you used to get the error message. Guess based on a common misunderstanding: If the file FILELIST_PROJECT.txt or $DirPath/FILELIST_PROJECT.txt contains relative paths, like sample_touch_FILENAME.CSV, the file paths are interpreted relative to the current working directory, not relative to this file or to a script location.
